# How to do API call in for loop in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

How we can perform same API call in for loop of array list of object :

```
private var emergencyContacts: ArrayList<Contact> = ArrayList()

    emergencyContacts.forEach
    {
        contactsViewModel.deleteEmergencyContactsAPI(it.id, it.id2)
    }

    fun deleteEmergencyContactsAPI(patientID: String, contactId: Int) {
        _deleteEmergencyContactsLiveData.postValue(Resource.loading())
        repository.deleteEmergencyContact(patientID, contactId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribeWith(DeleteEmergencyContactsResponse(_deleteEmergencyContactsLiveData))
    }

    inner class DeleteEmergencyContactsResponse(liveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<Status>>) :
        ResponseSingleObserverWrapper<Status, Status>(
            compositeDisposable,
            liveData
        ) {
        override fun onSuccess(t: Status) {
            _deleteEmergencyContactsLiveData.postValue(Resource.success(t))
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            _deleteEmergencyContactsLiveData.postValue(Resource.error(e.message ?: ""))
        }
    }
```

I want to perform UI execution after all API calls and it will not affect the screen performance.

I have tried with Zip operator , parallel network API calls but it not working nicely as API calls count is not static.

Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You tagged both rxJava and coroutines. Which do you want to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, for calls that require time to execute, you run them on a separate thread.

So, for that, you use `Coroutines`

now, if you want to execute something on a main thread from a seperate thread, `Coroutines` can do that too. here's an example.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    StuffYouWantOnADifferentThread()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        StuffYouWantOnTheMainThread()
    }
}
```

What happens here is, The `IO` Coroutine launches the `StuffYouWantOnADifferentThread()` on a background thread. Then, after that is executed, the `Main` Coroutine executes the `StuffYouWantOnTheMainThread()` on the main thread.

Comment: This is a recreation of callback hell using coroutines, but callback hell is one of the things that coroutines can solve! Use `withContext` instead of launching nested coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

As the rest api is still fetching data, for loop can hit next line.
To solve this i suggest adding data to adapter one by one inside the data fetching method.

```
public void addAll(CoinsMarketsModel newUsers)
    {
     marketModels.add(newUsers);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And to clear data,

```
public void clearAll(){
        this.marketModels = new ArrayList<>();
        marketModels.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Call *addAll()* at the last line of your api request response method.And *clearAll()* at the start of for loop.